# Title of Blog not Correct in Google Search

Tags: google-maps, search, web, blogs, blogger

I just created a new blog last week (made on blogger). I just recently changed the title of that blog a few hours ago and when searching my blog on google the original blog title still pops up.

I registered my blog on Google webmaster tools and fetched the homepage. However the original title of the blog still appears in Google search. Is there an alternative method to recrawl my blog or am I stuck with the original title in search?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no bearing on computer programming or software engineering.

Comment: @KevinDTimm So website development questions aren't allowed on this site?Hmmmm... These questions are allowed last time I checked.

Comment: Your question isn't about website development, it's about SEO - if you go to webmasters.stackexchange.com you'll find far more relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on several things, such as how many views the site gets, how you submitted the update, etc. Because you submitted the homepage to Google's Webmaster tools, it should update soon, in about a day or two. Some things you can do to help speed it up are submitting a sitemap, or getting some more views on your blog (no bot views).

Hope this helps!